# Mfence would be inserted by compiler to function using non atomic pointer storing value of atomic pointer

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, lock-free, carries-dependency

I am reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/carries_dependency) of carries_dependency attribute.
It seems to me that the following codes snippet from above link is telling that if `carries_dependency` attribute is not added to `print2` function, because of passing the non-atomic pointer `int* local` which is storing the value of atomic pointer `std::atomic<int*> p` to `print2`, compiler would insert a mfence.

I tried to verify above on https://godbolt.org/z/TTE4bM9d6 where has the exact same number of instructions as https://godbolt.org/z/K4Wd4sEG4 that means mfence was not inserted. I can understand because of the x86-64 gcc I used.
I tried to verify the same with ARM gcc trunk on https://godbolt.org/z/K6KM4nssK comparing with https://godbolt.org/z/jGYsae7dz. However, I have found got the same conclusion.

So my question is, is my understanding correct that from following snippet [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/carries_dependency) page is telling us mfence should be inserted by compiler if `carries_dependency` attribute is not added to `print2` function? If so, why I can't see get that from above tests on `Compiler Explorer`? If mfence should be inserted in this case, is it because local is a pointer which compiler takes it as a reference? However, the local pointer and p atomic pointer are pointing at address of x which is not an atomic variable. Why compiler would still insert mfence in this case?

PS I understand I am asking more than 1 question and I am expected to only ask 1 question per post, however, all questions above are closely related to each other. The background information would be redundant if I split each question per post.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
 
void print(int* val)
{
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;
}
 
void print2(int* val [[carries_dependency]])
{
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;
}
 
int main()
{
    int x{42};
    std::atomic<int*> p = &x;
    int* local = p.load(std::memory_order_consume);
 
    if (local)
    {
        // The dependency is explicit, so the compiler knows that local is
        // dereferenced, and that it must ensure that the dependency chain
        // is preserved in order to avoid a fence (on some architectures).
        std::cout << *local << std::endl;
    }
 
    if (local)
    {
        // The definition of print is opaque (assuming it is not inlined),
        // so the compiler must issue a fence in order to ensure that
        // reading *p in print returns the correct value.
        print(local);
    }
 
    if (local)
    {
        // The compiler can assume that although print2 is also opaque then
        // the dependency from the parameter to the dereferenced value is
        // preserved in the instruction stream, and no fence is necessary (on
        // some architectures). Obviously, the definition of print2 must actually
        // preserve this dependency, so the attribute will also impact the
        // generated code for print2.
        print2(local);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try ARM compilers, it makes more sense there.

Comment: @273K as mentioned above, I have tried both x86-64 gcc trunk & ARM gcc trunk compilers

Comment: `consume` is temporarily deprecated until it can be reworked into something compilers can actually handle.  In practice compilers treat `consume` as `acquire`, which x86 does for free.  (See also [What does memory\_order\_consume really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65336409) and more stuff linked from that, like https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0371r1.html).

Comment: You never need `mfence` for `release`/`acquire` on x86, only for `seq_cst`.  On 32-bit ARM, acquire loads will involve a `dmb ish` since there isn't a weaker barrier that's sufficient.  (@273K).  And if `consume` was actually implemented, then you'd see such a barrier before a call to a function that didn't promise it would respect `[[carries_dependency]]`

Comment: `print2` doesn't need any barriers except on Alpha; even weakly-ordered ISAs other than Alpha do guarantee dependency-ordering from pointer to value for a load (and for ALU operations on load results so stuff like `arr[i * 3 + 4]` still has a data dependency on `i`); avoiding barriers was the whole point of `consume`.

Comment: So in other words, in https://godbolt.org/z/rMa3PE55f, the `[[carries_dependency]]` means that the compiler *could* have omitted the `dmb ish` that appears at line 45 of the asm.  As Peter explained, current compilers don't actually attempt to do this optimization.  But without `[[carries_dependency]]` the barrier is mandatory.

Comment: (By the way, you probably want to be compiling with optimizations in your tests.  The main purpose of the C++ memory model is to specify, indirectly, what optimizations are or are not allowed.  If you are not optimizing to begin with, then you won't see much.)

Comment: Nothing involving `consume` (or even promoting it to `acquire`) requires flushing the store buffer.  Just compiler ordering is sufficient on x86-64, no special asm instructions are ever needed for memory ordering other than `seq_cst`.  (Or for RMW atomicity.)  Or `sfence` if you use NT stores, but that's outside of what `std::atomic` does.

Comment: Have you read the linked Q&As like [What does memory\_order\_consume really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65336409) and stuff linked from it?  [Memory order consume usage in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55741148) explains the hardware feature that `consume` is designed to expose.  [C++11: the difference between memory\_order\_relaxed and memory\_order\_consume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832012) links Paul McKenney's CppCon 2016 talk [C++ Atomics: The Sad Story of memory_order_consume: A Happy Ending At Last?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrNQKpOypqU), also very helpful.

Comment: If you don't understand why `acquire` doesn't need any special instructions on x86, see [C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179)