# Does std::mutex enforce cache coherence?

Tags: c++, caching, synchronization, mutex, atomic

I have a non-atomic variable `my_var` and an `std::mutex my_mut`. I assume up to this point in the code, the programmer has followed this rule:

> Each time the programmer modifies or writes to `my_var`, he locks
> and unlocks `my_mut`.

Assuming this, `Thread1` performs the following:

```
my_mut.lock();
my_var.modify();
my_mut.unlock();
```

Here is the sequence of events I imagine in my mind:

1. **Prior** to `my_mut.lock();`, there were possibly multiple copies of `my_var` in main memory and some local caches. These values do not necessarily agree, even if the programmer followed the rule.
2. By the instruction `my_mut.lock();`, all writes from the previously executed `my_mut` critical section are visible in memory to this thread.
3. `my_var.modify();` executes.
4. **After** `my_mut.unlock();`, there are possibly multiple copies of `my_var` in main memory and some local caches. These values do not necessarily agree, even if the programmer followed the rule. The value of `my_var` at the end of this thread will be visible to the next thread that locks `my_mut`, by the time it locks `my_mut`.

I have been having trouble finding a source that verifies that this is exactly how `std::mutex` should work. I consulted the C++ standard. From [ISO 2013](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf), I found this section:

> [ Note: For example, a call that acquires a mutex will perform an
> acquire operation on the locations comprising the mutex.
> Correspondingly, a call that releases the same mutex will perform a
> release operation on those same locations. Informally, performing a
> release operation on A forces prior side effects on other memory
> locations to become visible to other threads that later perform a
> consume or an acquire operation on A.

Is my understanding of `std::mutex` correct?

Comment: Of course it does, otherwise it would be useless.

Comment: @ixSci when I learned about it, I thought it was almost like an ```std::atomic<bool>``` that could be blocked and notified on unlock. Neither cppreference.com nor cplusplus.com mention cache cohesion. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: Cache cohesion isn't a term from C++ standard. You should not bother about the terms which aren't in the Standard as long as it guarantees some particular behavior (which is the case). Also mutex can be implemented as a spin-lock using `std::atomic<bool>` so in a sense they are "almost alike".

Comment: It might be helpful to realize that on modern systems, "main memory" is not the lowest layer. Another copy can exist on disk, in swap. C++ doesn't care a bit where all the copies are. It just assumes that things work as the Standard says they should.

Comment: Unless I am confused, this is called "cache coherence", not "cache cohesion". Am I confused?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ operates on the relations between operations not some particular hardware terms (like cache cohesion). So C++ Standard has a *happens-before* relationship which roughly means that whatever *happened before* completed all its side-effects and therefore is visible at the moment that happened after.

And given you have an exclusive critical session to which you have entered means that whatever happens within it, *happens before* the next time this critical section is entered. So any consequential entering to it will see everything happened before. That's what the Standard mandates. Everything else (including the cache cohesion) is the implementation's duty: it has to make sure that the described behavior is coherent with what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

> After `my_mut.unlock();`, there are possibly multiple copies of my_var in main memory and some local caches. These values do not necessarily agree, ...

Hardware already maintains cache coherence so conflicting copies in different caches are impossible on real-world systems. AFAIK, there are no C++ implementations that run `std::thread` across cores without coherent caches, and it's unlikely to be a thing in the future.  There are heterogenous systems like ARM DSP + MCU, but you don't run threads of one program between such cores.  (And you don't boot a single OS across such cores.)

There will be a value in DRAM for the address, but all CPU cores access memory through cache so that value doesn't matter: a Modified copy in another core's cache will take priority, thanks to hardware cache coherence.

See also

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol the standard cache-coherency protocol.  Modern CPUs don't use a shared bus, though, they use a directory (e.g. L3 tags) to keep track of which core might have a modified copy of any given line, so they know which core to signal to write-back a line a Read For Ownership (write miss) or share-request (read miss) happens for a line.
- [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118) (Never, except Linux kernel code which does roll its own `memory_order_relaxed` ops with `volatile` on GCC and Clang, with inline asm for more ordering when needed.  But cache-coherent hardware is why just `volatile` does work a lot like `atomic` with `relaxed`.)
- [Is cache coherency required for memory consistency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851091/is-cache-coherency-required-for-memory-consistency) including discussion in comments - implementing C++'s coherency requirements with manual flushing would be *very* onerous, e.g. every `release` store would have to know what parts of cache to flush, but the compiler normally doesn't know which variables are shared or not.  And worse, dirty write-back caches would need to get written back *before* writes from other cores so our later loads can actually see them.
- http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19 - *[Note 19: The four preceding coherence requirements effectively disallow compiler reordering of atomic operations to a single object, even if both operations are relaxed loads. **This effectively makes the cache coherence guarantee provided by most hardware available to C++ atomic operations.** — end note]*

---

Programs running on cores with non-coherent shared memory can use it for message-passing, e.g. via MPI, where the program is explicit about which memory regions are flushed when.  C++'s multithreaded memory model is not suitable for such systems.  That's why mainstream multi-CPU systems are [ccNUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access#CCNUMA); non-coherent shared memory can be found between nodes of a cluster, but again that's where you'd use MPI or something, not C++ threads across separate instances of an OS running on separate nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. "Not on real-world systems. AFAIK, there are no C++ implementations that run std::thread across cores without coherent caches. There are heterogenous systems like ARM DSP + MCU, but you don't run threads of one program between such cores..." My understanding of this is that you are saying the unlock will immediately flush to main memory and all other caches. Is my reading of your answer correct?

Comment: @MarkWallace: No, last-level cache works as a backstop for coherency traffic.  With coherent caches (often maintained using MESI - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), there can't be conflicting copies of data in cache.  A writer has to invalidate other copies of that line first, with a read-for-ownership if it didn't already have the line in Modified or Exclusive state. (i.e. if it didn't own it).  A reader will have to request that the line be shared if it doesn't have a valid copy and the coherency directory (e.g. L3 tags) says another core might have a modified copy.

Comment: You say "conflicting copies in different caches are impossible..." I am still reading that wiki and making sense of what you wrote, but I think you meant "conflicting copies are invalidated."

Comment: @MarkWallace: I actually meant what I said.  Invalidation happens *before* a core can commit a store into its L1d cache.  It needs to get the response to its RFO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Read_For_Ownership) confirming that other copies have been invalidated and that it has exclusive ownership.  (Some explanations of MESI are in terms of snooping a shared bus, unlike modern systems using a directory to avoid broadcasts.  But either way an RFO is still needed before a store.) Real CPUs may use an invalidation queue to hide some of the latency, but it's as if they wait.

Comment: @MarkWallace: Different cores storing conflicting values to the same location can have different values in their store buffer and each read different values for the same location temporarily, because store buffers aren't cache.  But only temporarily, and store buffers drain themselves ASAP, and memory-barrier instructions can wait for it to drain before later loads/stores happen.  [Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64141366) / [Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50609934)

Comment: @PeterCordes Does a mutex unlock wait for store buffer to be drained before releasing the mutex? Consider a scenario where we write to some variable in the critical section, but the store buffer hypothetically takes say 5 sec to drain. If we unlock the mutex with `release` semantics, and there was someone else waiting on the mutex so the kernel now goes to wake them up, isn't there a possibility that the other thread gets woken up before the variable write & mutex release are actually committed to cache?

Comment: @1110101001: Yes, this is what makes `memory_order_release` suitable for unlocking aka releasing a spinlock, hence the name.  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/). The release store committing to L1d cache makes it globally visible, so that has to wait for all older stores to commit first.  (Younger stores can still be in the buffer so it doesn't literally have to wait for it to be empty; think of it like a divider on a grocery-store conveyor belt, except it's only a one-way barrier for weakly-ordered ISAs.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I thought `release` only acts as a barrier to  prevent reordering of preceding loads/stores though, it doesn't explicitly wait for the store-buffer to be drained.  I agree that with a spinlock, `release` semantics for `unlock` work since when the T2 sees the mutex as available it is guaranteed that all of the side-effects before T1's mutex-unlock are committed to cache. But if you have a mutex that calls into the kernel--relying on the it to wake the other thread--then what prevents T2 from being woken before side-effects are committed?

Comment: @1110101001: Preventing earlier loads/stores from reordering with the release-store itself implies that earlier stores have to have already left the store buffer (and thus become globally visible) before the release-store can do the same.  If it needs to make a system call like Linux `futex` to wake other threads waiting, it has to do that *after* executing a release-store.  But yes, the kernel can start looking at its internal data structures before that release-store commits. However, the kernel's inter-core communication needs to also create happens-before sync, e.g. it does release-stores.

Comment: @1110101001: If the kernel didn't provide synchronization between the notifier and the waiter, the thread you woke up could see the lock still locked when it tried to take it.  So it would look like a spurious wakeup, and maybe call into the kernel to go back to sleep until the value isn't `x`.  But the kernel's atomic compare-and-sleep would probably see that it had already changed by then and wake that process back up.  (But that hypothetical design sounds racy, like you could end up with a missed wakeup and a thread going back to sleep with nobody holding the lock, nobody to wake them.)